# Show all emails in a list mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm certain this is a really easy question. I'm new to mysql.

I need to find all emails in a list that i have.

The list is about 40 emails.

```
this@gmail.com
that@gmail.com
another@gmail.com
onemore@gmail.com
```

I've tried this:

```
    SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_email = "'this@gmail.com',     'this@gmail.com'"


    SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_email = "this@gmail.com, this@gmail.com"


    SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_email in(this@gmail.com, this@gmail.com)
```

and various other queries. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ... customer_email IN ('this@gmail.com', 'this@gmail.com' /*, ...etc */)

Comment: 3rd try is ok just use quote on them

Comment: also, i don't need to show all the orders. Should i use DISTINCT?

Comment: yes but you can't wrap distinct around *, in that case if you need a specific field narrow your select down to the field and add distinct to your select clause

Comment: Thanks bud. I approved your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you want something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_email IN('this@gmail.com', 'that@gmail.com', etc)
```

you could also do this...

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_email = 'this@gmail.com' OR customer_email = 'that@gmail.com'
```

if you only need unique values then you can do this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(my_field) FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_email = 'this@gmail.com' OR customer_email = 'that@gmail.com'
```

as mentioned in my comment, `DISCTINT()` takes a single field as an argument you cannot put `*` as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try
SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_email IN('this@gmail.com', 'that@gmail.com')

Syntax is :
SELECT [COLUMN NAME] FROM [TABLE NAME] 
WHERE [COLUMN] IN ( [VALUE LIST] )

Note: your value list should be in '' if it is a varchar

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order ORDER by id ASC";
```

If you want it to display in descending format, change ASC to DESC

Happy coding!

Comment: this isn't what the question asked, they need only the email address that are in a given list